# what is need of Virtual directory in iis if we have Handler Mapping in iis

Tags: iis

I want to know waht is the need of Virtual Directory in IIS and its mapping, if we have Handler Mapping in IIS. Any request that goes to IIS server is handled by Handler Mapping in case of CGI or ISAPI , then why it is neccesory to craete a virtual directory having mapping to Physical directory of CGI application?

Any Resolution of my query would be highly appreciated.